# BlackBerry 10 PJSIP Implementation

Tags: sip, voip, pjsip, blackberry-10

As of late, I development a keen sense of interest in making a PJSIP app on the BlackBerry 10 platform. Has anybody managed to do such a thing? I have built the libraries as per instructions at https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/BB10 and of course, I now need to read up the documentation and whip out a BB10 app. It would be helpful to see some code to get me going.

Comment: I spoke with one of my colleagues on the BlackBerry Developer Relations team today, who indicated they are going to start working on a PJSIP sample and will publish as a 'hello world' style sample soon.

Comment: Thanks Adam. After much deliberation I have found myself on some sort of development path. Got the libraries to compile and now working on a pjsua style app. Yes I would very much like to have a look at the hello world sample. Let me know when its out. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We at Truphone contributed the patch with support for BlackBerry 10 to PJSIP. It is not yet complete, and we're readying another patch to add support for some bluetooth and HDMI connections for audio routing.

Anyways, once its all compiled up, you'll need to write a wrapper to connect PJSIP with the app runloop. To get that rock-solid for all events is not trivial. We'd be happy to open ours up as an open source project, if there was enough interest.

Comment: Hi Adam. Many thanks. I built a working PJSIP app for BB10. Currently tiding it up so I can release it.